# JPARepository trying to save a Entity on another .save after a @Query

Tags: java, database, jpa, jparepository

Im trying to do a query from TokenEntity and after a save on HistoricoTituloEntity but when I try to save the HistoricoTituloEntity it goes to TokenEntity.

```
    public interface TokenJPARepositoryTest extends JpaRepository<TokenEntity, Integer>{
    
    @Query(" select t FROM TokenEntity t  WHERE t.codBanco = ?1 ")
    TokenEntity obterToken(Integer codBanco);

}
    @Service
public class HistoricoTituloServiceImpl implements HistoricoService{
    
    @Autowired
    HistoricoTituloRepository historicoTituloRepository;
    
    public Integer salvaHistoricoTitulo(HistoricoTituloEntity historicoTituloEntity) {  
        historicoTituloRepository.save(historicoTituloEntity);
        return historicoTituloEntity.getIdHistTitulo();
    }
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it goes to TokenEntity"?

Comment: your question is unclear. Where is the code that does what you explained? i.e. the query then saving. I only see the methods supposedly called, but not the caller.